# How to calculate factorial using prolog

Tags: prolog, factorial

I have a code for calculating factorial as below :

```
fact(1,1).
fact(X,R):- X1 is X-1, fact(X1,R1), R is R1*X.
```

In my mind this code shouldn't work right but it does! What is my reason? I think when we call fact(3,R), first it calculate "**X1 is X1 -1**". Then it goes to next rule **fact(X1,R1)**. This will call the goal part again and the code execution will return to the goal "**fact(X,R)**" and this will continue until we reach to fact(1,1). It means it never goes to 
**R is R1*X** part. So, it seems I am thinking wrong.

Can anyone tell me step by step about the code execution order in this code?
Thanks

Comment: `fact(1,0)` does not terminate.  And also `fact(1,1), false` loops, although it should fail. However, `fact(1,1)` will produce an answer thus luring you into some safety. Always ask for the next answer to make sure you have not an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once we "reach" the `fact(1,1)`, it will "return" to the calling recursive iteration and proceed to the part `R is R1*X` of that iteration, with `R1=1`. Then will return again to a previous level and so on. Let's look at a non-trivial iteration:

```
fact(3,R) :
   X <- 3,
   X1 <- 3-1 = 2,
   fact(2,R1) : 
      X' <- 2,
      X1' <- 2-1 = 1,
      fact(1, R1'), => R1'=1 (matched from fact(1,1)) 
      R'<- R1' * X' = 2
      R1 = R' = 2
   R <- R1*X = 2*3 = 6.
```

Here the variable with `'` are denoting the variables corresponding to the `fact(2,R)` iteration. The variables without `'` are for the topmost iteration.

Comment: Please edit your answer with fact(3,R) because this is where I get confused. I wanna know what will happen when between 2 and 3 as X!

Comment: In `fact(3,R)` the fourth line will match `fact(2,R)`, which is described in the answer, and therefore returning with `R=2`.  The rest is the same

Comment: I edited your answer in order that the other users can trace fact(3,R) step by step. But still couldn't understand the last part R <- R1*X = ???. Please complete it. How fact(3,R) results in 6?

Comment: But why in line 9, you write R1=R'=2? How R1=R'?

Comment: R1 of the top iteration is matching the R of the inner one.